# Check Duplicate Node VivaGraph js

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, vivagraphjs

I want to check node exist or not before create a new node. From VivaGraph GitHub documentation I cant find anything.

Comment: check the source code then. there must be something written.

Comment: Why don't you create an array of contains nodes. So you can check if there is a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
graph.getNode(id)
```

with graph being your VivaGraph instance, which would return `null` if no node with the given id exists. It is automatically called by `graph.addNode(id, data)`, so it is not possible to create two nodes with the same id anyway.